# What is the "unambiguously correct" pictogram for database storage?

Tags: data-visualisation

I want to draw a mockup design of a set of microservices forming a web application. I need to represent a database storage in it. I would like to know if there is  consensus on which pictogram is accepted as representing the *storage* of the data in the database (not the database application itself).

Comment: "Correct" may not be the best word, in your title. Perhaps "standard" is more correct.

Comment: I take the point @RadLexus - the word is rife with connotation. perhaps a better adjective would be  "unambiguous" ?

Comment: Yes, that's better :) It would only need to be unambiguous *in your context*, that is, if it appears in between several other icons to store other data, say, plain text or images. I guess you'll have to judge that by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, from what I know the most used icon for data storage is:

[image]

[ [image source](http://downloadicons.net/database-sql-icon-60170) ]

[image]

[ [image source](http://www.123rf.com/photo_22514515_database-data-center-and-data-storage-icons-blue-version-vector.html) ]

[image]

[ [image source](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/292904/data_database_server_storage_icon) ]

You could possibly get away with a cloud storage icon:
[image]

[ [image source](http://www.123rf.com/photo_25263186_cloud-data-upload-icon-uploading-file-document-photo-music-or-video-on-cloud-storage-database-as-a-b.html) ]

..or a combination of the two:
[image]

[ [image source](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/824648/cloud_computing_data_database_mainframe_rack_server_storage_icon) ]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's close to what I'm looking for - except I want it to explicitly convey that it's SQL-like data. So the generic "storage" pictograms are not going to cut it. My feeling is that http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf7gW.png comes closest ?

Comment: @brucellino That does come first. I've added another icon for SQL at the top of my answer. Bottom line is, that what you should be going for.